# Galileo's pendulum and any references

Tags: experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, harmonic-oscillator, history, experimental-technique

In some texts about the simple pendulum we use to see references about some "experiments" Galileo Galilei did realize and whereby he found some important results, including that the period of the pendulum is proportional to the square root of the lenght of the (stem of the) pendulum. I would like to know if there is any book ou document wrote by Galileo (on the Dialogues or the Discourses) where I can find the explanation about these experiments realized by Galileo.

Comment: I don't know which one is better according to the policies of the sites but you might consider asking the same question on hsm.stackexchange.com . Just a suggestion! :)

Comment: in fact, i did not know about the existence of hsm. What an i supossed to do know? Exclude this question. I'm gonna create an account in hsm :) thanks.

Comment: We can migrate this question to [hsm.SE] if it's determined to be off topic here. Alternatively, if you post the question there yourself, make sure to delete it here.